# question of update data in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM activites";
$queryc = mysql_query($query); 
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($queryc))
{ 
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr><th colspan="3"><form action="CRUD/modiftitle.php" method="POST"><input    type="text" name="title" value="'.$row['title'].'" /><input type="submit" name="modify" value="Modify" /></form></th></tr>';
  echo '</table><br />';
 }
echo '</center>';
?>
```

i have this code, the problem is that when i try to modify one data all o them will be the same as the modified!
here is the modify file:

```
<?php
$connection = @mysql_connect(localhost, 'root', '');
if (!$connection){
  echo 'not connect';
}
mysql_select_db('bena');

//Update content
$content = $_POST['content'];
$sql = "UPDATE activites SET content = '$content'";

$result = mysql_query( $sql, $connection );
if($result)
echo "Update was successfully complete! ";

?>
```

Comment: Where did your code go? It was sufficient already to have it in the question

Comment: @Jon: They probably saw an old version before you fixed the formatting. @aida: Please indent code by four spaces (push the `{}`) button in order to make it show up in your question. Put the rest in there as well, as it's impossible to read as a comment.

Comment: Comments are for comments, not for expanding your question. Please put your code in the actual question body by clicking the Edit button under the tags.

Comment: There a huge security loophole in `UPDATE activites SET content = '$content'`; **always** use proper escaping functions (here: `mysql_real_escape_string`) or, better, use parametrized SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `UPDATE activites SET content = '$content'` needs a WHERE statement, which describes what objects that should be updated

Comment: jon thanks for replay but how? i mean how can take a WHERE condition that i want to update this data